# How to put Variable or function in ORA_ERR_TAG$ column in ERROR_LOG table ORACLE

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have a small snippet of my code below ..I am not able to insert into error_log table ORA_ERR_TAG$ column.If I remove the variable  v_errblk then it works fine.
How can I achieve the variable information in the tag.

```
 Declare
     v_errblk NUMBER (2):= 0;
    BEGIN
    v_errblk := 1;
    update....;
    Commit;
    v_errblk := 2;
    update ....
    commit;
    v_errblk = 3;
    insert into test3
    Select * FROM   test1
      WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM   test2 WHERE  test1.Abc = test2.abc)
     LOG ERRORS ('ERROR BETWEEN BLOCK:' || v_errblk || 'AND' || v_errblk + 1||'') REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;

    END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `v_errblk + 1` is hurting you here. I originally thought it was a limitation of the `LOG ERRORS` expression, but if you try something as simple as this it will fail with an `ORA-01722: invalid number`:

```
select '1 + 2 = ' || 1 + 2 from dual
```

Try putting parentheses around `v_errblk + 1`:

```
LOG ERRORS ('ERROR BETWEEN BLOCK:' || v_errblk || 'AND' || (v_errblk + 1))
```

Also, I'd get rid of the trailing `|| ''`. It's not needed.

Comment: WOW..ur the man...thanks a lot Ed..It worked fine after your changes...Thanks a ton